# How to distribute designable / inspectable custom views with Carthage

Tags: swift, carthage

is there a way to distribute a custom IBDesignable / IBInspectable UIView control in a framework with Carthage?

Here is a demo framework:

https://github.com/exchangegroup/MyCustomView

It has a [designable `MyCustomView`](https://github.com/exchangegroup/MyCustomView/blob/master/MyCustomView/MyCustomView.swift) with an inspectable property `myBorderWidth`.

[image: custom_class]

The designable view shows in the storyboard of the the framework project.

[image: inspectable_works]

But, if I include this framework in another app with Carthage, the storyboard does not allow to design the `MyCustomView`.

Here is a demo app that [uses it with Carthage](https://github.com/exchangegroup/UsingMyCustomView/blob/master/Cartfile):

https://github.com/exchangegroup/UsingMyCustomView

[image: inspectable_does_not_work]

Is there a way to way to distribute designable UIView with carthage?

Tested  in Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7.

Carthage: 0.6.4

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you need to include a bundle that is linked in the host app that contains your assets (storyboard).
If you want them to be able to drag a uiview into a storyboard, see your custom design and/or edit it that's a little tricky. If your uiview overrides awakeafternib you can actually design it in such a way that you can simply drag them into storyboards and they fully render without needing an additional container view . I'm not aware of a way to edit your original storyboard view as if it were a template.